# How to preserve directory structure, dates and attributes when copying dir trees in Windows on FATxx volumes?

Tags: windows, backup, fat32

Is there a tool (sync, backup or copy like) that can do for directory trees on a FATxx partition what an utility like Norton Ghost does for whole volumes?

A tool that, while copying directory trees, preserves file CAM dates, directory MC dates AND the "." and ".." sublinks MC dates with the usual attribute preserving and source tree sorting?

Now, although I do know the answer to that question, I would really like to stop wasting time in a disk editor after such copy tasks. NTbackup comes very close, but directory pointers still have the current date. Vcopy (Verbatim Copy) does the same without creating a intermediate file. Close, but legacy data needs its metadata.

Any other tool or time to rewrite a script that I did a long time ago for MSDOS - change the system time, create a dir, revert clock and then copy away?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows XP or newer, [Microsoft's ROBOCOPY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) does keep the source date/time and you can keep links and attributes and ACLs (security). You can also use the `/MIR` command to mirror a directory structure completely, including deletes though.

For Windows Vista and above, it's built in. For Windows XP and Server 2003, it's available in the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657)

Comment: If I remember correctly, when I did run ROBOCOPY a few years ago it did not even preserve the directory creation date, let alone the "." and ".." FAT sublink dates.
/n
It is simple to see what I want. Comparing output of DIR /S from source and target trees should NOT produce any diffs.

Comment: @knjers Even with the `/MIR` command?

Comment: @Luke You should write the switch to use in your answer. If robocopy's default doesn't do what he wants or might not, then you should say so and say the switch he needs within your answer. Or suggest the switch.  Though as he says, it is -easy- to check, so if you think a switch does it, you  could check it and tell him if it does. Or make clear in your answer that you don't know what switch if any, then suggest it in comment.

Comment: @barlop Done edit